# ANTLR4: [Modes] Need multiple lexer rules for whitespace?

Tags: antlr, whitespace, token, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I am creating a parser for input like this:

```
FirstName, LastName, Street, City, State, ZipCode
Mark,, 4460 Stuart Street, Marion Center, PA, 15759
----
FirstName=John
LastName=Smith
```

The data before the `----` separator is in CSV format and the data after the `----` separator is in key/value format. So I have two sets of lexer rules and I use the ANTLR `mode` to switch between the lexer rules.

The problem is this: I need a lexer rule for whitespace in both sets of lexer rules and ANTLR doesn't allow the same rule name in both modes. So I have resorted to naming it `WS` in one mode and `WS2` in the other mode:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;                  

COMMA  : ',' ;
NL     : ('\r')?'\n' ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
SEPARATOR : SEP NL -> skip, pushMode(PAIRS) ;
STRING : (~[,\r\n])+ ;

fragment SEP : '----' ;

mode PAIRS ;
KEY       : ('FirstName' | 'LastName') ;
EQ        : '=' ;
NL2       : ('\r')?'\n' ;
WS2       : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
VALUE     : (~[=\r\n])+ ;
```

Ditto for newlines: `NL` in one mode and `NL2` in the other mode.

That works but it is not aesthetically pleasing. Is there a more aesthetically pleasing way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Two improvements to suggest:

1) If your parser is modeless (only needs to deal with eg NL's - realize that this might not be the case in this specific example)

```
NL2 : ('\r')?'\n' -> type(NL);
```

2) Then, just a bit of clean-up:

```
NL  : Nl;
...
NL2 : Nl; 
...
fragment Nl : ('\r')?'\n' -> type(NL);
```

In all, this is mostly rearranging deck chairs, but it is about the most that you can do.